# Spring & dirtiescontext & AnnotationTransactionAspect

Tags: java, spring

I use Spring 4.1.2. Junit 4 and SpringJUnit4ClassRunner with DirtiesContext.

After Spring destroys the old context and creates the new one I can see that all beans are new. BUT they are proxied by the same AnnotationTransactionAspect classes. What's interesting is that those AnnotationTransactionAspect-s(TransactionAspectSupport) have a new beanFactory! But at the same time they have old transactionManagerCache-s that caches old connections from the previous test (and those connections are already closed after spring was shut down at the end of the first test).
Why Spring does not create new AnnotationTransactionAspects?

P.S. It seems that I started facing the problem after migrating from spring 3.X to 4.X.

Comment: Debug information: The AnnotationTransactionAspect constructor is called only once before the first test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was a bug in Spring. https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12518 It was fixed in 4.1.4

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get how to fix AnnotationTransactionCreation. I made a hack. 
Create a proxy for PlatformTransactionManager

```
public class TestTransactionManager implements PlatformTransactionManager {
private static List<TestTransactionManager> transactionManagerList = new ArrayList<>();

private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

public void init() {
    transactionManagerList.add(this);
    for (TestTransactionManager m : transactionManagerList) {
        m.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
    }
}

public void setTransactionManager(PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
    this.transactionManager = transactionManager;
}

@Override
public TransactionStatus getTransaction(TransactionDefinition transactionDefinition) throws TransactionException {
    return transactionManager.getTransaction(transactionDefinition);
}

@Override
public void commit(TransactionStatus transactionStatus) throws TransactionException {
    transactionManager.commit(transactionStatus);
}

@Override
public void rollback(TransactionStatus transactionStatus) throws TransactionException {
    transactionManager.rollback(transactionStatus);
}
```

}

and put it into test application context

```
<bean id="testTransactionManager" class="ru.bpc.core.integration.stub.TestTransactionManager" init-method="init">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="testTransactionManager"/>
```